# Spaces when concatenating multiple columns and one column is null - Oracle

Tags: oracle, null, concatenation, space

I need to concatenate several columns into one, with spaces between each value. The problem is when one value is null, I end up with a double space between two values.

Example

```
SELECT (FIRST_NAME || ' ' || MIDDLE_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME
  FROM TABLE_A;
```

If the middle name happens to be NULL, then I end up with two spaces between the first and last name. Any way to get around this and only have one space when there's a null value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another option is to use decode :

```
SELECT decode(FIRST_NAME,'','',FIRST_NAME ||' ') ||
       decode(MIDDLE_NAME,'','',MIDDLE_NAME ||' ') || LAST_NAME
FROM TABLE_A;
```

Comment: I ended up using the NVL() method you had posted before. I did figure out that the table had some values that were blank (or so I thought) but actually had a space, so those rows were messing with me

Comment: ...I take that back. I had to incorporate the decode as in the above. Thanks for the help

Comment: Since `''` is null in Oracle, the `nvl` calls here add nothing of value. "If FIRST_NAME is null, return null, otherwise return FIRST_NAME" is the same as "return FIRST_NAME".

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT TRIM(TRIM(FIRST_NAME || ' ' || MIDDLE_NAME) || ' ' || LAST_NAME)   
FROM TABLE_A;
```

Comment: This one is the most correct, as the accepted approach doesn't suppose that the first two arguments could be NULL.

Answer (score 5):

From the Oracle's documentation:

> CONCAT_WS(separator,str1,str2,...)
>
> CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special
>   form of CONCAT(). The first argument is the separator for the rest of
>   the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be
>   concatenated. The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the
>   arguments. If the separator is NULL, the result is NULL.

And the very important comment:

> CONCAT_WS() does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any
>   NULL values after the separator argument.

So in your case it should be:

```
CONCAT_WS(',', FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `CONCAT_WS()` is available in MySQL, not Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

```
with indata as
(
select 'John' as first_name, 'W' as middle_name, 'Smith ' as last_name from dual
union
select null as first_name, null as middle_name, 'Adams' as last_name from dual
union
select 'Tom' as first_name, null as middle_name, 'Jefferson' as last_name from dual
)
select
regexp_replace(trim(indata.first_name || ' ' || indata.middle_name || ' ' || indata.last_name), '\s{2,}', ' ')
from indata;
```

Comment: ha! just about to post the regexp_replace methodology!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I typically concatenate several fields and remove whitespace in Oracle:

`TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(HOUSE_NO || ' ' || PREFIX || ' ' || STREET_NAME || ' ' || STREET_TYPE || ' ' || SUFFIX, ' +', ' '))`

1. Concatenate all the fields necessary with a space in between each. Empty strings and NULL values will result in a two or more spaces;
2. Use a regular expression to change any occurrences of multiple spaces [' +'] to a single space [' '];
3. Finally, trim any whitespace at the beginning and/or end from the resulting string.

Comment: I used regexp_replace for this problem but did it as REGEX_REPLACE( <concatenation>, '\s{2,}', ' ') to look for 2 or more whitespaces in a row.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`RPAD()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm) to add in the space character:

```
SELECT RPAD(first_name, LENGTH(first_name)+1, ' ')||RPAD(middle_name, LENGTH(middle_name)+1, ' ')||last_name
FROM TABLE_A;
```

When any of the parameters to `RPAD` are NULL, the result will be NULL, and in Oracle appending NULL to a string returns the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
SELECT first_name
       || DECODE(middle_name
          ,      NULL, NULL
          ,      ' ' || middle_name)
       || DECODE(last_name
          ,      NULL, NULL
          ,      ' ' || last_name) full_name
FROM   table_a
;
```

Comment: if middle_name or last_name is empty string (i.e. '') -  it doesn't work properly...

Comment: In Oracle it will; Oracle makes no distinction between the empty string and `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply use the REPLACE function:

```
with indata as 
  (select 'John' as first_name, 'W' as middle_name, 'Smith ' as last_name from dual 
   union 
   select null as first_name, null as middle_name, 'Adams' as last_name from dual 
    union 
    select 'Tom' as first_name, null as middle_name, 'Jefferson' as last_name from dual) 
SELECT REPLACE(TRIM(indata.first_name || ' ' || indata.middle_name || ' ' || indata.last_name), '  ', ' ')
  FROM indata
```

(And thanks to @tbone for the example data :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have this work around with example. Hope this helps. Just go to SQL server, select new query and CP following query:

```
DECLARE @NULL_SAMLES TABLE
       (
       NS_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED NOT NULL
      ,COL_01 VARCHAR(10) NULL
      ,COL_02 VARCHAR(10) NULL
      ,COL_03 VARCHAR(10) NULL
      ,COL_04 VARCHAR(10) NULL
   )

   INSERT INTO @NULL_SAMLES(COL_01,COL_02,COL_03,COL_04)
   VALUES
    ('A','B','C','D')
   ,(' ' ,'B','C','D')
   ,(' ',NULL,'C','D')
   ,('A','B',NULL,'D')
   ,('A','B','C',NULL)
   ,(NULL,'B',NULL,'D')
   ,(NULL,'B','C',NULL)
   ,('A',NULL,'C',NULL)
   ,('A',NULL,NULL,'D')
   ,('A',NULL,NULL,NULL)
   ,(NULL,'B',NULL,NULL)
   ,(NULL,NULL,'C',NULL)
   ,(NULL,NULL,NULL,'D')


   SELECT
        NS.COL_01
       ,NS.COL_02
       ,NS.COL_03
       ,NS.COL_04,
      Stuff(  
        Coalesce(', ' + nullif(NS.COL_01, ''), '') 
      + Coalesce(', ' + nullif(NS.COL_02, ''), '') 
      + Coalesce(', ' + nullif(NS.COL_03, ''), '') 
      +Coalesce(', ' + nullif(NS.COL_04, ''), '')
      , 1, 1, '') AS CONC_COLS
   FROM @NULL_SAMLES NS
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't underestimate the simple power of the CASE statement, which can be concatenated. Here's a self-contained example you can run as-is:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN x.FIRST_NAME IS NULL THEN x.FIRST_NAME ELSE x.FIRST_NAME || ' ' END || 
CASE WHEN x.MIDDLE_NAME IS NULL THEN x.MIDDLE_NAME ELSE x.MIDDLE_NAME  || ' ' END || 
x.LAST_NAME
FROM (SELECT 'John' AS FIRST_NAME, NULL AS MIDDLE_NAME, 'Doe' AS LAST_NAME FROM DUAL) x;
```